# YOLOv3 Model Structure: Why is filters = (classes + coords + 1) * num?

Tags: computer-vision, yolo, darknet, models, filters

Here's a tutorial about doing custom training of YOLO (Darknet): https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/how-to-train-yolov3-to-detect-custom-objects-ccbcafeb13d2

The tutorial guides how to set values in the `.cfg` files:

- classes = Number of classes, OK
- filters = (classes + 5) * 3

**Why is it 'plus 5' then 'times 3'?**

Some say it's (classes + coords + 1) * num, but I can't guess it out the meaning.

Comment: 3 boxes per feature map and for every box you predict class probabilities + width + height + x + y + object confidence.

Comment: uhm, and what is that 'coords'?

Comment: well its x, y, height and width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @brale in the comment below the question:

```
filters = (classes + 5) * 3
= (classes + width + height + x + y + confidence) * num
= (classes + 1+1+1+1+1) * num
= (classes + 5) * num
```

YOLOv3 dectects **3 boxes per grid cell**, so it is:

```
filters = (classes + 5) * 3
```